# Google Maps SDK - custom dimensions for info window

Tags: swift, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

Trying to figure out how to customize the dimensions of the info window that comes up after tapping on a marker on the map.

As a default, it's not large enough to display the pertinent information in a convenient way.

What I am hoping to achieve is a fullscreen view of the title and snippet.

will venmo $5 to anyone who can solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom UIView and design using the storyboard which you would like to appear as your info window.

Implement the delegate method `markerInfoWindow` to return the custom view by loading your desired view from the storyboard. It's pretty straight & simple.

Comment: Hi Gurdev,
Thanks for the help. I'm a bit new to this. Would you be able to describe the process a bit more? Having some trouble turning your comment into code.

Comment: 1. Implement `mapView:markerInfoWindow` delegate method in your ViewController.
2. Implement the function below.

func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
   let customInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
   customInfoWindow.label1.text = 'Custom text'
   customInfoWindow.label2.text = 'any additional info.'
   // you can define any custom objects in your CustomInfoWindow nib and set its properties in this method.
   return customInfoWindow
}